# My code won't read the 10th row when i'm typing 10 and also how can i exit my program when i input negative number?

Tags: java

My code won't read the 10th row when i'm typing 10 and also how can i exit my program when i input negative number?

here is the error.

```
Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space  (Enter a negative number to exit): -1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at SeatReservation.main(SeatReservation.java:33)
```

here is my code:
i use string instead of int. i think that is the gonna be alright but now i can't use the code (seatNumber < 0) on my if. i want to use it so when i input negative string number the program will exit. also when i input 10 on my row it can't read it.i can't use substring because it is string and not int. help me i'm confuse and new to this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SeatReservation {
     
     static int filled = 0 ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        char[][] seats = new char [10][4] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            seats[i][0] = '*' ;
            seats[i][1] = '*' ;
            seats[i][2] = '*' ;
            seats[i][3] = '*' ;
        }

        String seatNumber = " " ; 
        String q = " " ;
        System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation:") ;
        printSeats(seats) ;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        seatNumber = keyboard.nextLine() ;
        if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Program exit!") ;
                    System.exit(0) ;
                } 
        while((filled < 40) && (seatNumber.length() > 0))
        {
            int row = seatNumber.charAt(0) - '1';
            int col = seatNumber.charAt(2) - '1';
            if (row < 0 || row > 10 || col < 0 || col > 4)
            {
                System.out.print("Input error. Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space  (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
                seatNumber = keyboard.nextLine() ;
                if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Program exit!") ;
                    System.exit(0) ;
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                if (seats[row][col] != 'X')
                {
                    seats[row][col] = 'X' ;
                    filled++ ; 
                    printSeats(seats) ;
                }
                if (filled < 40)
                {
                    seatNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if (seatNumber.equals("q"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Program exit!") ;
                        System.exit(0) ;
                    } 
                }
            }
        } 
        printSeats(seats); 
    }

    private static void printSeats(char[][] seats)
    {
        System.out.println("         Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4") ;
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(("Row "+ (i + 1)) + "\t" +
                " |"+seats[i][0] + "      " + seats[i][1] + "       " + seats[i][2] + "        " + seats[i][3]) ;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space  (Enter a negative number to exit):");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

please help me with this. thank you so much!

Comment: Remove `javascript` tag in your question. `java` is *not* `javascript`

Comment: convert `seatNumber.charAt(0)` to integer before subtracting. And when subtracting use a number literal, not a char or string literal.

Comment: "i can't use substring because it is string and not int. help me i'm confuse and new to this." I'm also confused, you CAN'T use substring because it's a string?

Comment: Which line is line 33? Please add a comment on that line.

Comment: i suggest you refrain from using `charAt` and use string.`split` instead since you can have an input with 2 characters e.g 10

Comment: change to `if (row < 0 || row >= 10 || col < 0 || col >= 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the basic problem is, you want to ask the user, repeatedly, to enter a value until they either enter `"q"` or a negative number.

So this immediately screams `do-while loop`.  You need to do at least one loop, to get the input, at which time you can decide what to do with it

```
boolean shouldEnd = false;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    String seatNumber = " ";
    System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation:");
    printSeats(seats);
    seatNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (seatNumber.equals("q") || isNegativeNumber(seatNumber)) {
        shouldEnd = true;
    } else {
        // All the processing which needs to be done   
    }
    System.out.println("");
} while (!shouldEnd);
```

Testing for a negative value is a little more involved, as the `String` needs to be converted to an `int` value first and you need to be willing to deal with the scenarios where the input is not a numerical value.  To this end, a little helper method comes into play.

```
private static boolean isNegativeNumber(String input) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(input) < 0;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, onto the processing of the input.  `String` manipulation can be tricky and you need to be willing to deal with the all the possible scenarios where the input is in the format that you are expecting.

I've assumed that the input is in `row` [space] `col` format.  To this end, we can simply split the input on the space and check to see that we have two values, for example....

```
String[] parts = seatNumber.split(" ");
if (parts.length == 2) {
    // More processing   
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please use [row] [col]");
}
```

Processing the input then comes down to simply converting the input values you have into `int` values, verifying the inputs are within range and applying them...

```
try {
    int row = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) - 1;
    int col = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
    // Remember, you've zero index'ed your values, so it's 0 to 9 and 0 to 3
    // not 0 to 10 and 0 to 4
    if (row < 0 || row > 9 || col < 0 || col > 3) {
        System.out.println("Input error. Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space");
    } else {
        if (seats[row][col] != 'X') {
            seats[row][col] = 'X';
            filled++;
        }
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    System.out.println("Row/col input should be numeric value");
}
```

You will note that I only use a single input request and only print the seats once in the whole workflow.  Each time the loop runs again, the seats are printed and the input is requested.  This simplifies the workflow and makes it easier to manage

I've not checked the `filled` state, I'll leave you to do that.

All the above put together, might look something like...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeatReservation {

    static int filled = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] seats = new char[10][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            seats[i][0] = '*';
            seats[i][1] = '*';
            seats[i][2] = '*';
            seats[i][3] = '*';
        }

        boolean shouldEnd = false;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            String seatNumber = " ";
            System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation:");
            printSeats(seats);
            seatNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (seatNumber.equals("q") || isNegativeNumber(seatNumber)) {
                shouldEnd = true;
            } else {

                String[] parts = seatNumber.split(" ");
                if (parts.length == 2) {
                    try {
                        int row = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) - 1;
                        int col = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
                        // Remember, you've zero index'ed your values, so it's 0 to 9 and 0 to 3
                        // not 0 to 10 and 0 to 4
                        if (row < 0 || row > 9 || col < 0 || col > 3) {
                            System.out.println("Input error. Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space");
                        } else {
                            if (seats[row][col] != 'X') {
                                seats[row][col] = 'X';
                                filled++;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                        System.out.println("Row/col input should be numeric value");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please use [row] [col]");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } while (!shouldEnd);
    }

    private static boolean isNegativeNumber(String input) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(input) < 0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void printSeats(char[][] seats) {
        System.out.println("         Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4");
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(("Row " + (i + 1)) + "\t"
                    + " |" + seats[i][0] + "      " + seats[i][1] + "       " + seats[i][2] + "        " + seats[i][3]);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space  (Enter a negative number to exit):");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is very helpful and i learned a lot with your explanations. Keep safe and God bless to you! 